# Twitter Oauth c# Getting screenName

Tags: c#, twitter, oauth

I have looked for different packages for c# to can make a Oauth Authentication and from the ones I have seen, the one that best work seems to be Tweetinvi.

With this project I am able to get the access token of the user after the authentication, but can't get the user's id and screenName. To be able to get this information I need to make a verify_credentials request to the Twitter API and looks like for Tweetinvi is a feature that won't be developed soon https://tweetinvi.codeplex.com/workitem/1724.

Any possible way to get the user id and the screenName? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This feature is already implemented in Tweetinvi:

```
var user = User.GetLoggedUser();
```

If you want to get it from a specific set of credentials:

```
var userFromCredentials = User.GetLoggedUser(credentials);
```